# Angular Push Notification - Avoid storing duplicate subscription objects

Tags: angular, push-notification, service-worker, angular-service-worker

I have referred multiple code snippets and almost everywhere the code for requesting permission to allow push notifications using angular is similar to this:

```
export class AppComponent {

    constructor(swPush: SwPush) {
        if (swPush.isEnabled) {
            swPush.requestSubscription({
                serverPublicKey: VAPID_PUBLIC
            }).then(subscription => {
                // save subscription object in db
            }).catch(console.error);
        }
    }

}
```

---

I have implemented the same in my application, but I'm facing this issue -

First time a user loads the application, browser will ask for permission and if the user 'Allows', the promise will be resolved and subscription object will be stored in db.

Next time when the user loads the application, since the permission is already granted, the promise will be resolved and subscription object will again be stored in db. So there will be duplicate entries in db.

---

To avoid duplicate entries in db, I would like to understand which of these 2 solutions is better (or if there is any other better approach):

**1.** Call swPush.requestSubscription iff there is no active subscription

```
export class AppComponent {

    constructor(swPush: SwPush) {
        if (swPush.isEnabled) {
            swPush.subscription.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(subscription => {
                if(subscription == null) {
                    swPush.requestSubscription({
                        serverPublicKey: VAPID_PUBLIC
                    }).then(subscription => {
                        // save subscription object in db
                    }).catch(console.error);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**2.** Let swPush.requestSubscription be called everytime on page load and handle insertion of duplicate db entries in the server side code.

Answer (score 2):

The [Notification browser API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/permission) has a `permission` field which synchronously indicates the current state of acceptance "default", "granted", or "denied". You can check this status and only request permission if it's in the "default" state.